# Converting list of dictionaries into bytes_stream

Tags: python, database, dictionary, binary-data, bytestream

I am trying to convert the type of the data fetched from the database into the `binary` type. The data fetched from the database is in the form of a list.
Below is the sample code:

```
def WriteData(data):

    jsonData = json.dumps(data)
    binaryData = ' '.join(format(ord(letter), 'b') for letter in jsonData)
    print(type(binaryData))
    filePointer = io.BytesIO(binaryData)
```

The output of the code is:

`<class 'str'>`

Comment: This is really unclear. Why do you need to do this? What is the required output? What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: `' '.join()` will create a string.

Comment: `binaryData` is a string. So it's perfectly correct that `print(type(binaryData))` prints `<class 'str'>`. What were you expecting it to print? And what are you _really_ trying to do? Converting text codepoints to space-separated variable length strings of zeros & ones doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: If you must do this, why not `binaryData = bytearray(jsonData, encoding='ascii')`?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking since BytesIO takes bytes as a parameter you want to convert the json dumped data to bytes. For this you can just use encode() method

```
def WriteData(data):

    jsonData = json.dumps(data)
    binaryData = jsonData.encode()
    print(type(binaryData))
    filePointer = io.BytesIO(binaryData)
```